# Run controllers only after initialization is complete in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, initialization

I have some global data that needs to be loaded before any controller is executed in my AngularJS application (i.e. resolve dependencies globally in AngularJS).

For example, I have a `UserService` with the `getCurrentUser()` method which does a request to the backend server in order to get data about the currently authenticated user. And I have a controller that needs this data in order to launch yet another request (for example to load user's balance).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: An interesting question, but can you explain the reason why do you want to achieve that?

Comment: I need to access some global data in my ngRoute resolves and inside of controllers. For example, I need to get user's balance for some view, but it can be fetched only by knowing the accountId which is obtained during application initialization (call to getCurrentUser).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Update

Please consider using method specified in the «[Asynchronously Bootstrapping AngularJS Applications with Server-Side Data](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data)» article if possible.

You can use the [angular-deferred-bootstrap](https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap) module to achieve that now!

---

I'm not sure about validity of this answer anymore, you can still use the ideas, but be sure to properly test it with your actual code. I will try to keep this answer up to date with never technologies.

## Old answer

There are several approaches to the problem of asynchronous application initialization.

When it comes to data that must be resolved before a single controller is called - you can easily use `resolve` option of `ngRoute`'s `$routeProvider`. However, when you need some global data to be loaded before ANY controller is called - you have to improvise.

I've tried to collect all possible solutions in this answer. I'm providing them in the order of preference.

### 1. Using *ui-router*

When using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead of native `ngRoute` you can create an abstract root state and resolve all data in it, before sub-states are activated.

I would recommend to use this approach. `ui-router` provides a lot of additional features including ability to resolve dependencies hierarchically and is well accepted by the developer community.

#### Example

```javascript
module.config(function($urlRouterProvider, stateHelperProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');
    stateHelperProvider.setNestedState({
        name: 'root',
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        abstract: true,
        resolve: {
            user: function(UserService) {
                // getCurrentUser() returns promise that will be resolved
                // by ui-router before nested states are activated.
                return UserService.getCurrentUser();
            }
        },
        children: [{
            name: 'index',
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/partials/index'
        }, {
            name: 'not-found',
            url: '/404',
            templateUrl: '/partials/404'
        }, {
            name: 'balance',
            url: '/balance',
            templateUrl: '/partials/balance',
            resolve: {
                balance: function(UserService, user) {
                    // Using data resolved in parent state.
                    return UserService.getBalanceByAccountId(user.accountId);
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

The [`stateHelper`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#statehelper-module) will help greatly to reduce the code when using abstract root scope approach.

Root scope is defined as abstract so can not be activated directly and it has no URL.

`template: '<ui-view/>'` is required for nested views to be properly rendered.

### 2. Making promises in root controller

You can make promises and add them to the `$rootScope` inside of your root controller, i.e. `run()` function.

I've created a Plunk to demonstrate the idea:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gpguG5Y2S4KOz1KOKzXe?p=preview

This is a perfectly working solution, however, it bloats the code and makes it harder to use and understand (callback hell). I would recommend it only if the first approach is not working for you.

### 3. Passing data with the application page

You can include all initialization data directly to the HTML page generated on the server and access it from your application.

Consider this example:

```html
<html>

<body>

    <script src="application.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        application.init({
            // Pass your data here.
            userData: { ... }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And you can bootstrap AngularJS application manually in the `init()` method of your custom `application` object.

I don't really like this approach, as I do believe that frontend and backend of Web application should be highly separated. Ideally, your frontend should be a static website (e.g. bunch of HTML, CSS and JS that can be delivered via CDN) and your backend should be a strictly an API server without a presentation layer (i.e. it should know nothing about HTML, CSS and such). However, it's a working solution if you can live with tight integration between application components.

Comment: A million thanks, you have ended 3 days of pain! I wasn't using DI with ui-router `resolve` properly and your clear example helped get me on the right track.