# Angular JS - $http.get as part of app.run() that I need to be synchronous

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am making a `$http.get` request in an `app.run()` block to set some `$rootScope` variables. The issue is that the code that uses those `$rootScope` variables is running before those variables are set because the call is asynchronous. It's also in a different js file.

It seems like I should use jquery to make the http call (I can make it synchronous using jquery), rather than trying to make a `promise` or `defer` object visible across the files.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050496/run-controllers-only-after-initialization-is-complete-in-angularjs Does it help?

Comment: never use synchronous calls... they are being deprecated by browser vendors who are now throwing deprecation warnings in console if you use them