# Angular app initialization with asynchronous data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to initialize my Angular with some User data that the whole app depends on. Therefore I need the initialization to be resolved before the router kicks in and controllers are initialized.

Currently, I wrote the initialization code in a `run()` block of the angular module. The initialization involves an asynchronous http request to get user data and the rest of the application relies upon the user data.
How can I ensure that the http request is resolved before the router kicks-in initializing the controllers?

I am using the ui-router.

The initialization consists in the following:
1) get cookie 'userId'
2) get User from server (asynchronous http request, the whole app depends upon the User)
3) set authService.currentUser

this is a sample of the code

```
.run(['$cookies', 'userApiService', 'authService', 
  function($cookies, userApiService, authService){

    var userId = $cookies.get('userId');
    userId = parseCookieValue(userId);

    userApiService.getOne(userId).then(function(user){
      authService.currentUser = user;
    });
}])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', 
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/main');

    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
          'header': {
            templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
          },
          'content': {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
          },
          'footer': {
            templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
          }
        }
      })
      .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        views: {
          'content@': {
            template: '',
            controller: function($state, authService) {
              if(!authService.isAuthenticated()) {
                $state.go('login');
              }
              if(authService.isStudent()) {
                $state.go('student');
              }
              if(authService.isAdmin()) {
                $state.go('admin');
              }
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .state('student', {
        url: '/student',
        views: {
          'header@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
          },
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/student.html',
            controller: 'StudentCtrl'
          },
          'footer@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
          }
        }
      })
      .state('admin', {
        url: '/admin',
        views: {
          'header@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
          },
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/admin.html',
            controller: 'AdminCtrl'
          },
          'footer@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
          }
        }
      })
}])
```

Comment: Look into the `resolve` property. You can define it on the root state

Comment: Thanks @NewDev, could you give me some guideline to define the root state? For the moment I added the resolve property to the `main` state, but if I understood you correctly this is not the root state, correct? -- I am new to ui-router --

Comment: Also @NewDev, could you explain how to pass a parameter to `resolve` property? For instance, I want to display student information with matching `student_id`. Thank you.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin if you have another question, it would be better to ask in a new separate question

Comment: @klode, I meant by "root" that it's the state that all other states (that require the user id) descend from, since child states inherit the parent's resolved values.

Comment: @NewDev I understand now, since I did not have a parent state in the example code I was confused.

Comment: this answer is a nice summary of possible solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050496/run-controllers-only-after-initialization-is-complete-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on someone's comment, you can *create* a `root` state that is a parent to all of your other app's states (children to the root). The `root` state resolves all the user data and then you can inject the user data to any controller or store it in a service.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('root', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    template: '',     // some template with header, content, footer ui-views
    resolve: {
      // fetch user data
    }
  })
  .state('root.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'header': {
        templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
        controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
      },
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      },
      'footer': {
        templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
      }
    }
  })
  .state('root.main', {
    url: '/main',
    views: {
      'content@': {
        template: '',
        controller: function($state, authService) {
          if(!authService.isAuthenticated()) {
            $state.go('login');
          }
          if(authService.isStudent()) {
            $state.go('student');
          }
          if(authService.isAdmin()) {
            $state.go('admin');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  ...  // your other states
```

The key is that all of your app states must be a child of your `root` state i.e. `root.<name>` in your state declaration. This will ensure that no other controller starts until your user data is available. For more information on `resolve` and how to use it [read here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve). Also, [parent and child states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views).